# Как создать экземпляр TableView

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

**Я хочу создать приложение для аэропортов в JavaFX.
Вот как создать это представление с помощью CSS.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой случай.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Style.css Файл

```
.root{
    -fx-background-color: black;
 }
.label{
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, derive(cadetblue, -20%), 10, 0, 4, 4);
}

#tableView .column-header{
    -fx-background-color: #373d3d;
    -fx-text-fill: rgb(207,234,254);
}
.table-view .column-header,
.table-view .column-header-background,
.table-view {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
.table-view .column-header .label {
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: #373d3d;
    -fx-font-size: 32px;
    -fx-text-fill:  white;
    -fx-padding: 1 0 1 0;
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, derive(cadetblue, -20%), 10, 0, 4, 4);
}

.table-column {
    -fx-border-color: -fx-background-color;
    -fx-font-size: 32px;
    -fx-text-fill: rgb(207,234,254);
    -fx-font: bold;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, derive(cadetblue, -20%), 10, 0, 4, 4);
}
.table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, #262626;
    -fx-border-color: #262626;
 }

.table-row-cell:odd{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, #373d3d;
 }
```

Sample.fxml  Файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="535.0" prefWidth="849.0" styleClass="root" stylesheets="@Style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.Controller">
    <children>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="599.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="333.0" text="ПРИЛЕТЫ" textFill="WHITE">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="52" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="405.0" prefWidth="640.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="Vaqt" prefWidth="99.0" text="ВРЕМЯ" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="Rasm" prefWidth="162.0" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="Reys" prefWidth="106.0" text="РЕЙС" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="Mashrut" prefWidth="175.0" text="МАШРУТ" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="Status" prefWidth="99.0" sortType="DESCENDING" text="СТАТУС" />
                    </columns>
               <columnResizePolicy>
                  <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
               </columnResizePolicy>
                </TableView>
                <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="640.0">
                    <children>
                        <Label prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="599.0" text="01.02.2018" textFill="WHITE">
                            <font>
                                <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="29.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="599.0" text="16:30" textFill="WHITE">
                            <font>
                                <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="29.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Label>
                    </children>
                </HBox>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller.java Файл

```
   package controllers;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import modells.TableData;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by Loving on 14.12.2018.
 */
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    private Timer timer;
    @FXML
    TableView tableView;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TableData,String> Vaqt;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TableData, ImageView> Rasm;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TableData,String> Reys;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TableData,String> Mashrut;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TableData,String> Status;



    List<TableData> list=new ArrayList<TableData>();
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        timer=new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView("img/uzairways_logo.jpg");
                ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView("img/uzairways_logo.jpg");
                list =new ArrayList<TableData>();
                list.add(new TableData("12:10", imageView1, "HY 615", "Москва", "прибил в 12:15"));
                list.add(new TableData("14:30", imageView2, "HY 52", "Ташкент", "по расписанию"));
                tableView.getItems().clear();
                tableView.getItems().addAll(list);
                System.out.println("Va va");

            }
        },5001);
        Vaqt.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("time"));
        Rasm.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, ImageView>("imageView"));
        Reys.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("flight"));
        Mashrut.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("destination"));
        Status.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String>("status"));
        ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView("img/uzairways_logo.jpg");
        ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView("img/uzairways_logo.jpg");
        ImageView imageView3 = new ImageView("img/nordwind-airlines-logo.png");
        ImageView imageView4 = new ImageView("img/uzairways_logo.jpg");
        ImageView imageView5 = new ImageView("img/S7-airline-logo.png");

        list.add(new TableData("12:10", imageView1, "HY 615", "Москва", "прибил в 12:15"));
        list.add(new TableData("14:30", imageView2, "HY 52", "Ташкент", "по расписанию"));
        list.add(new TableData("15:40", imageView3, "S7 966", "Ташкент", "по расписанию"));
        list.add(new TableData("17:05", imageView4, "HY 966", "Санкт-Петербург", "по расписанию"));
        list.add(new TableData("18:50", imageView5, "S7 966", "Москва", "по расписанию"));
        tableView.getItems().addAll(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы не рассматривали вариант сделать такое через `ListView`, из кастомных контролов `HBox`, куда в конструктор передавать объект, содержащий данные для каждой строки?

Comment: Как сказали, такое лучше сделать `ListView`. Можно сделать отдельный `fxml` файл который будет описывать вашу строку.